# Parsing HTML from a string

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var 
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    d = parser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0"?><div class="a">Hello</div>', 'application/xhtml+xml');

console.log(d.querySelector('*'));
console.log(d.querySelector('div'));
console.log(d.querySelector('div.a'));
```

The first two selectors work

The last selector.... the class selector.... returns null :(

Any ideas why?

Needing this to query html results from AJAX, and dont want to add it to the main DOM to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
console.log(d.querySelector('div[class=a]'));
```

Comment: And yours does work.  Someone vote this answer up higher than mine!  :)

Comment: Mark, does your method work because using div.a is an invalid selector?  And div[class=a] is valid?  I tried searching a bit, but I'm not 100% what this terminology is...I keep getting css examples where div.a IS valid.

Comment: div.a is valid, but I still don't know why, it works with jQuery but not with document.querySelector
And div[class=a] is also valid, but it's from CSS3, so some old browsers don't support this selector

Comment: This is the confusing bit.  Selecting "div.a" will work on the document of the HTML page, but not on a DOMParser document.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

Because your html/xml is invalid.  Try changning `</a>` to `</div>`

Comment: Thank you Joseph.  I didn't know how to make html tags appear in the post.  And, I'm sorry Mark Linus.  I just initially saw the unmatched tags.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the pick up.  Doesn't fix the issue, but I think Mark Linus below has the answer.

Comment: Actually, the both are right. The best to do is to correct your script basing on both answers